# Radio input return incomplete string

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor

I've got radio buttons in MVC Razor like this

```
<td style="min-width:110px" align="center"><label for="naraName">@listOfNames[i]</label></td>
<td style="min-width:110px" align="center"><input type="radio" name="naraName" value=@listOfNames[i] /></td>
```

which in HTML look like this:
[image]

But problem is, that this radio button return incomplete string. It should return "na na na nara" but only return "na" like this

[image]

Any ideas, how to fix this?

Comment: Isn't the value property of radio button supposed to be in double quotes? i. e. `<td style="min-width:110px" align="center"><input type="radio" name="naraName" value="@listOfNames[i]" /></td>
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add quotes

```
<input type="radio" name="naraName" value="@listOfNames[i]" />
```